# Pandas DataFrame - Test for change/modification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Simple question, and my google-fu is not strong enough to find the right term to get a solid answer from the documentation. Any term I look for that includes either change or modify leads me to questions like 'How to change column name....'

I am reading in a large dataframe, and I may be adding new columns to it. These columns are based on interpolation of values on a row by row basis, and the simple numbers of rows makes this process a couple hours in length. Hence, I save the dataframe, which also can take a bit of time - 30 seconds at least.

My current code will always save the dataframe, even if I have not added any new columns. Since I am still developing some plotting tools around it, I am wasting a lot of time waiting for the save to finish at the termination of the script needlessly.

Is there a DataFrame attribute I can test to see if the DataFrame has been modified? Essentially, if this is False I can avoid saving at the end of the script, but if it is True then a save is necessary. This simple one line if will save me a lot of time and a lost of SSD writes!

Comment: You probably want to vectorize your row by row solution which is highly inefficient.

Comment: I am looking into that. The problem is I am using scipy.interpolation.interp1d() to perform the interpolation for each row, and it is the big drain. I am using DataFrame.apply() to apply the interpolation function throughout the drataframe, which appears to be faster then something like iterrows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.equals(old_df)
```

You can read the it's functionality in [pandas' documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html). It basically does what you want, returning `True` only if both DataFrames are equal, and it's probably the fastest way to do it since it's an implementation of pandas itself.

Notice you need to use [`.copy()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) when assigning `old_df` before changes in your current `df`, otherwise you might pass the dataframe by reference and not by value.

Comment: OK - that looks close to what I am after. Was hoping for a internal check of a single dataframe then a comparison between two, but I will take what I can get!

Comment: What do you mean by an "internal check"?

Comment: Sorry if I used the wrong phrase. For instance, `if df.have_I_changed: df.to_csv('saved.csv) `, where `have_I_changed` is a simple `True` or `False` that is set to `True` whenever the dataframe is modified from its state when created. If I understand your suggestion, I will essentially have to copy the loaded dataframe immediately upon load, and keep it separated until the end. When the dataframe is a couple of 2.3gb (and it is actually a subset), keeping a copy is something I have to be careful of.